# How to wake up / enter system after slock?

Tags: xmonad

I'm using `xmonad` as my window manager. There's no default hibernate/lock app by default.

I tried `slock`, it locked my screen; however, I don't know how to re-enter the system: there's just a black screen, and nothing works.

How can I enter the system?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To unlock `slock`, simply type your user password at the blank screen.

You can verify this is the process via [slock's readme](http://git.suckless.org/slock/tree/README).

Comment: Wow, that's so simple. I thought there must be some place to input password. It is radically simple!

Comment: Oh God! I can't believe I Googled this!!! :D